# What are the .rxxxxk .rxxxxl file extensions?

Tags: archive, file-type, file-type-associations

I have a set of files with the following extensions, does anyone recognise the filetype?

I've tried googling with no success, my best guess is it is some form of multi-part archive format.

```
.\files (3)\krnuis01.48002504.r1117l
.\files (3)\krnuis01.48002505.r1118k
.\files (3)\krnuis01.48002505.r1118l
.\files (3)\krnuis01.48002506.r1119k
.\files (3)\krnuis01.48002506.r1119l
.\files (3)\krnuis01.48002509.r1120k
```